# neo4j-APOC plugin stopped working

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

Plugin `APOC` was working for me for a long time which means I have it copied at right place and I have edited `config` file correctly. But today I needed to create same graph on different data set so I stopped neo4j service, removed database directy, restarted it, changed password then copied plugins directory in neo4j directory(as I'm not using shell) and again restarted neo4j serivice. Then tried to execute the same query again and got error messgae. 
`There is no procedure with the name apoc.create.relationship registered for this database instance.` and the query I'm using is as following

```
CALL apoc.create.relationship(n, network.connection, {}, m) yield rel
```

I have made following change based on a stackoverflow post,
uncommented following line

```
#dbms.directories.plugins=plugins
```

and added plugin directory path, restarted service even restarted system but still not working. I have done this(removing neo4j directory...) in past multiple times but this has never happened to me. Even I have tried replacing old apoc.jar with newly downloaded one before. I have neo4j3.3.0 with apoc3.3.0.1jar with windows10. Can anybody tell me what have I done wrong this time? Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: when I uncomment above line in `config` file my other plugins also stop working but after commenting it other plugins like `graph algorithms` are working but not `APOC`

Comment: does CALL apoc.help('apoc') works ? 
I assume you did not change of server/install, else it could just be that you did not give the auth. to Apoc for running (sthg with whithelist in neo4j.conf)

Comment: no it doesn't work and I have whitelisted and unrestricted it in neo4j.config file as it was working properly before.

Comment: can you link to the post you are referring to ?
Is there anything useful in the logs

If there is the previous Apoc Jar in same folder, move it elsewhere. Or rename it to .jarold
Could be simply that

Comment: I am talking about [warnig](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*` and `dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*` I just checked logs it says `The procedure 'apoc.create.relationship' is not on the whitelist and won't be loaded.` same messages for all other `apoc` procedures but I have whitelisted it already and I don't have old jar in same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know what the problem was, I uninstalled it with logs and config files, downloaded latest version which didn't pose any headaches of editing config file for csv files and for plugins and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using APOC procedures and graph algorithms, I think you have configured your config file this way:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=algo.*
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
```

If it is the case, change these lines to:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=algo.*,apoc.*
```

Comment: I made these changes at the first place but didn't work, both plugins were working before with separate permissions.
I really don't know what the problem was, I uninstalled it with logs and config files, downloaded latest version which didn't pose any headaches of editing config file for csv files and for plugins and it worked.

Comment: @RazaUlHaq great! So I suggest you to answer your question with your solution and accept the answer as the right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If someone is reading this question and has done everything correctly. Set the correct permissions on the plugins directory, uncommented the whitelisted and unrestricted sections of the /etc/neo4j.conf, checked if the version of the Apoc jar you're loading is the same version as neo4j, etc. and can't make it work.

Try to restart your PC, that was what did it for me, for some weird reason.